# How does train travel work?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I was under the impression that trains were a fast travel option, or at least moderately fast.

I got a train ticket in Valentine, to head to Saint Denis. I don't really know what happened but a few minutes had passed and the train was still going. I again kept waiting for a long time (over 10 minutes) and never arrived in Saint Denis.

I assumed the train would stop and kick me off when it got to the correct destination, and I also assumed it would have been much faster.

I ended up robbing people on the train and left when it was stopped at Wallace Station.

Has anyone else had a never ending train ride?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you travel by train, the game will briefly show you sitting in the carriage, after which you get a transition screen (like when you sleep) and arrive at the destination.

It sounds like you experienced some kind of bug.

Answer (score 2):

Not a bug. Fast travel only happenes if you press the board train command (triangle) if you have a ticket otherwise, you can use it to travel if you dont want to fast travel and get more immersed un the game.